# throw new exception("Test"); does not throw my text

Tags: c#, try-catch, throw, unhandled-exception

```
throw new Exception("Test");
```

only Throws 
[image: Window]

I can't get my Text in there...

I also tried

```
throw new ArgumentException("Test");
```

and with a `try` `catch` and without.

But it is my written throw that makes the window.

Edit:
Im working my way around so it is not possible that the throw comes.

Comment: Throwing an exception with the message is not equal to showing a Message Box with the message. What do you want to do? If you want to show a message, use MessageBox.Show("Test") in WinForms.

Comment: did you try catching the exception in the "Catch" block. Also, make sure you don't have "Break on all errors" checked under visual studio settings.

Comment: And if you want to make your own exception with custom text, you need to implement your own custom exception class that derives from Exception.  Eg. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/agileer/2013/05/17/the-correct-way-to-code-a-custom-exception-class/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to `catch` the exception and extract the message to display.

```
try
{
     //Your code here
}
catch(Exception e)
{
     var message = e.Message;
     MessageBox.Show(message);
}
```